# Bootstrap 3 Collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my coding of navbar. When I switch to mobile view navbar works fine, but when I add some php content like include some pages by using using include function of php, then its stop working  collapsing.

```
    enter code here     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Navbar</title>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>





<!--<!-- Nav bar fixed to top-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#head">Mohit Sharma</a>

            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><img src="images/newlogo.png" /></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#training">Training <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#slogan1">Contact</a></li>
               </ul>

               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><img src="images/newlogo.png" /></li>

              </ul>



            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav><!-- /.navbar -->








</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you got any errors in your js debugger ?

Comment: Where exactly are you including php content?

Comment: @YenneInfo no errors.. you see my problem on my website www.mohit0043.esy.es

Comment: @DimasPante like simple php page with some image or wording. by using  <?php  include('header.php'); ?>  like this and before this i m adding  <?php  include('navbar.php'); ?>.  when i alone run navbar.php everthing works fine but after adding another php file i got problem.

Comment: Hmm can you show your code after you put the includes?

Comment: @DimasPante  this my navbar coding----------